# Not able to enter user input in while loop

Tags: java

My program is a simple divisibility checker for some practice. I am trying to take a user input if the user wants to re-run the program. When I run the program, it takes the user input for the number but the input statement for exiting the program is just not working. Please see the code below for reference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
            int number = input.nextInt();

            if (number % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println("Divisible by 5");
            else if (number % 3 == 0)
                System.out.println("Divisible by 3");
            else
                System.out.println("not divisible by 3 or 5");
            System.out.println("Wanna do it again??(y/n)");
            String response = input.nextLine();
            if(response=="n")
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `nextInt()` followed by `nextLine()` causes this bug. Change your `nextInt()` into a `nextLine()`, then transform the resulting String into an int using `Integer.parseInt(String value)`

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help. I changed nextLine() to next() and it worked.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. I see that your question was closed. The link they attached to it also has some good information, so I encourage you to take a look.